# Modifying Binary Save Game Data (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, binaryfiles

Just for fun, I'm trying to hack my saved game data for the Ghostbusters iPhone app ([AppStore link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ghostbusters/id583354857?mt=8&uo=4)).

The following sites describe replacing `Documents/save.dat` with the pre-hacked version:

- http://www.iapphacks.com/ios-free-hacks-f3/ghostbusters-v1-0-1-t8597.html
- http://mobilegamingsquad.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/ghostbusters-hack/

However, I want to modify the data myself.  Using a hex-editor on my `save.dat` revealed the following dead-ends:

1. I could not find the value for the amount of money in any combination of the following: (little endian, big endian), (unsigned, signed), (integer, float), (4, 6, 8, 16 byte value), (1 through 15 byte offsets)
2. Any small change (ie: item purchase) seems to completely rewrite and change the data file.
3. A quick scan of the file in ASCII reveals no text clues to the format of the file.  *ADD:* In fact, all ASCII strings within the file seem completely random.
4. The linux command `file` simply identified the file as `data`.
5. *NEW* Compressing the file enlarges it, so the file is likely compressed or encrypted.
6. *NEW* I'm neither jailbroken nor an iOS developer, so I do not have access to the app's internal memory.

How might this file be encoded?  Any suggestions on how I might modify it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar just for the fun of it. In my case, the file was compressed and contained a hash signature with a salt value generated by the game executable. In that case, I used `gdb`, set breakpoints on all hash functions and inspected their arguments. I am actually not sure how one would go about debugging an iPhone application, but I suspect it is not possible unless you jailbreak the device, so you are probably stuck trying to analyze the files.

Start by downloading HexField (or a similar tool), it is really great for this type of work. Try to find a pattern based on really small changes (try really hard to change as little as possible, and make sure you kill the game after changing something). If you are lucky, the scores, money and whatnot is just obfuscated.

If do not easily see a pattern in the file I would start by investigating known compressions such as gzip (without header), deflate, lzma, etc (start by looking at the symbol table and use class-dump on the game binary for some ideas). Since the `file` command gave nothing, I assume the file is not simply gzipped.

Failing that, you may start to suspect that the file is encrypted (again, look at the symbol table). A good way to determine if the file is compressed or encrypted is to try to compress it. If no algo is able to compress it further, it is very likely that the file is either compressed or encrypted.

Happy hacking! :)

Comment: Great ideas!

I'm neither jailbroken nor an iOS developer, so I don't have access to memory.  I too suspect it's compressed or encrypted as compressing the file enlarged it.